# jQuery append content of hidden elements to a visible element

Tags: jquery, append, blogger, blogspot

First, I am a jquery novice; second, I need to keep this simple based on the following code unless you note errors I have missed. A more sophisticated approach can come later. The following function is intended to copy the URL-query content of four hidden DIVs (left visible for now) into a central content DIV. This approach is necessary to bypass max. 17 records/posts returned for URL query on a Blogger site.

```
function loadContent(targetElement, sourceURL, sourceElement) {
var mytarget = $(targetElement); // cache the initial
mytarget.hide().empty();
$("body").scrollTop(0);
$("#tempElement1").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true .post-start.row");
$("#tempElement2").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=17&by-date=true .post-start.row");
$("#tempElement3").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=34&by-date=true .post-start.row");
$("#tempElement4").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=51&by-date=true .post-start.row");

mytarget.append($("#tempElement1").html());
mytarget.append($("#tempElement2").html());
mytarget.append($("#tempElement3").html());
mytarget.append($("#tempElement4").html());

}
```

The page's code can be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/a/nobledead.org/uc?id=0Bzd09tGp2OU8YUV0VWZpN0JhNFU&export=download

The live test page can be viewed here: http://www.ndauthorservices.com/p/gallerytestjc.html

Comment: So what's the problem? What is happening and what *should* happen?

Comment: You are (will be) experiencing problems with the code above because you are appending the content of the hidden `div`s without checking if the `load()` action has completed. As it probably hasn't (the `append` is right below the `load` calls), the result is that the `mytarget` element will always be empty. You need to look into using [`when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/); or having a variable that is updated when each `load()` completes, and only update `mytarget` when all the requests are completed.

Comment: Nothing gets copied to the target element from the hidden ones (tempElement*). The "when()" is something I will go read up on as soon as possible.  I tried using appendTo() but that just moved the tempElement(s) into the target. Need to move the content (only) of those divs into target.

Obviously a better way would be loading into variables, but as said, I am a novice who hasn't figured out that trick yet. --JC

Comment: ADDITIONAL: The tempElements are loaded by the time the rest of the code fires. If not, using appendTo would not have copied the whole tempElements into the target. The example of that is not live at this time... and obviously I am using "append" the wrong way. So....?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `append`. As said before, you are appending empty `div`s, that's why nothing gets copied to the target: there is nothing to copy. You are appending right after doing the load, but `load` is an asynchronous function, so by the time that you use `append`, it has not completed the request yet (and the tempElement* are still empty).

Answer (score 0):

You are (will be) experiencing problems with the code above because you are appending the content of the hidden `div`s without checking if the `load()` action has completed. As it probably hasn't (the `append` is right below the `load` calls), the result is that the "mytarget" element will always be empty because the hidden elements are initially empty:

```
<div id="tempElement1"></div>
<div id="tempElement2"></div>
<div id="tempElement3"></div>
<div id="tempElement4"></div>
```

One quick solution for this issue would be to:

1. Create a variable that keeps track of how many of the loads have completed (e.g.: `loadedDivs`).

   ```
   var loadedDivs = 0;
   ```
2. Add a function that is executed after each `load`:

   ```
   $("#tempElement1").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
   $("#tempElement2").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=17&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
   $("#tempElement3").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=34&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
   $("#tempElement4").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=51&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
   ```
3. Create that `allLoaded()` function, and in it:

   - Increase the value of `loadedDivs` by 1.
   - If the value of `loadedDivs` is the same as the number of `load`s you called, then do the append (all the loads will have completed successfully).

   In this case, it would look like this:

   ```
   function allLoaded() {
       loadedDivs++;
       if (loadedDivs == 4) {
           mytarget.append($("#tempElement1").html());
           mytarget.append($("#tempElement2").html());
           mytarget.append($("#tempElement3").html());
           mytarget.append($("#tempElement4").html());
       }
   }
   ```

And that should be it. You are doing the append correctly, the only issue is that you are running it ahead of time. The ending result would look like this in your code (scroll to see the last part of the `load`):

```
var loadedDivs = 0;
var loadElement = null;

function allLoaded() {
    loadedDivs++;
    if (loadedDivs == 4) {
        loadElement.append($("#tempElement1").html());
        loadElement.append($("#tempElement2").html());
        loadElement.append($("#tempElement3").html());
        loadElement.append($("#tempElement4").html());
    }
}

function loadContent(targetElement, sourceURL, sourceElement) {
    var mytarget = $(targetElement); // cache the initial
    loadElement = mytarget;
    mytarget.hide().empty();
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    $("#tempElement1").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
    $("#tempElement2").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=17&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
    $("#tempElement3").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=34&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);
    $("#tempElement4").load("http://www.ndauthorservices.com" + sourceURL + "&start=51&by-date=true .post-start.row", allLoaded);

    Shadowbox.setup("a.coverpreview", {      
        viewportPadding: 40
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro, but no, didn't work. I did learn a little more though. 

See source I used here: https://docs.google.com/a/nobledead.org/uc?id=0Bzd09tGp2OU8YUV0VWZpN0JhNFU&export=download

See live test here: http://www.ndauthorservices.com/p/gallerytestjc.html

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake. `mytarget` is not defined in the allLoaded function. I updated the code, try with the new function. See how now there is a new variable (`loadElement`) that is set in `loadContent()` and used in `allLoaded()`

Comment: Still not copying content of tempElements to mytarget/targetElement which is "storeContainer" as passed by the links in the markup. Maybe I have some error in the markup? Or maybe my loadElement calls are not correct?Also, eventually, I want to copy the content of "loadElement" in those four lines rather than the tempElements as a whole. Am I doing those calls correctly? You can see my layout in a link from my previous response.

Comment: I don't really understand your comments: if I go to the page that you linked, it works fine and it's loading everything OK when I click on the menus.

Comment: Also, nobody should have to go to your site to see the error: the code will change and the issue will be impossible to reproduce making the question useless for other people. The code and a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be present directly in the question

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and I am still learning proper etiquette for this site. Previously I have had no complaints when presenting links to a test page and/or mark-up file. As to the test page working fine, that is incorrect. The content you are seeing is still being displayed in the "temp" divs and not moved into the targetElement (storeContainer) between the two horizontal menus. It appears the loadElement functions are not working... which may be a problem with how I implemented them. I left the tempElements visible so that content retrieval could be check visually.

Comment: Alvaro, I have edited your answer above to add lines of code to reveal "mytarget" that were missing. However, this did not solve the problem of copying the tempElements into the "mytarget" element.  Also, loadedDivs needs to be reset to zero after each completion of a load upon clicking a link... I think?

Comment: If you want to copy the whole div into "mytarget", then you don't need to do the `.html()` part. For example, you would just need to use `loadElement.append($("#tempElement1"));` then tempElement1 will be moved into loadElement. I check your code and it's still using the old version instead of the new one above. Did you get a chance to try that one?

Comment: will try again later and report back. ADDITIONAL: I do not want to copy the entire tempElements into the storeContainer. Those temps need to remain for further use of visitors browsing the gallery. Should I be using another approach?  I tried appendTo but of course that was all wrong. --JC